# Creating custom PersistenceParticipant

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am trying to write a sample PersistenceParticipant for my application.

It is not storing  the properties in  the [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancePromotedProperties]

The workflow doesnt seem  to be giving any error but would not do the save as  well.

```
  public class MyPersistanceParticipant : PersistenceParticipant
{
    public string MovieName;
    public string Rating;
    public Decimal Price;
    static XNamespace xNS = XNamespace.Get("IamaUniqueNamespace");


    //static XNamespace test = XNamespace.Get("clr-namespace:MovieRental.DataModel;assembly=MovieRental.DataModel");
    //static XName currentCountName = stepCountNamespace.GetName("MovieName");

    protected override  void CollectValues(out IDictionary<System.Xml.Linq.XName, object> readWriteValues, out IDictionary<System.Xml.Linq.XName, object> writeOnlyValues)
    {
        //readWriteValues = new Dictionary<XName, object>();
        //readWriteValues.Add(xNS.GetName("MovieName"), this.MovieName);
        //readWriteValues.Add(xNS.GetName("Rating"), this.Rating);
        //readWriteValues.Add(xNS.GetName("Price"), this.Price);
        readWriteValues = null;
        writeOnlyValues = new Dictionary<XName, object>();
        writeOnlyValues.Add(xNS.GetName("MovieName"), this.MovieName);
        writeOnlyValues.Add(xNS.GetName("Rating"), this.Rating);
        writeOnlyValues.Add(xNS.GetName("Price"), this.Price);
        //base.CollectValues(out readWriteValues, out writeOnlyValues);
    }
    protected override void PublishValues(IDictionary<XName, Object> readWriteValues)
    {
        object loadedData;
        if (readWriteValues.TryGetValue(MovieName, out loadedData))
        {
            this.MovieName = (string)loadedData;
        }
    }
    protected override IDictionary<XName, object> MapValues(IDictionary<XName, object> readWriteValues, IDictionary<XName, object> writeOnlyValues)
    {
        return base.MapValues(readWriteValues, writeOnlyValues);
    }
}
```

I have added the persistence store to the application using below code

```
      MyPersistanceParticipant ps = new MyPersistanceParticipant();
            _wfApp.Extensions.Add(ps);
```

I have also added the code activity

```
 public class MakePersistanceHappen : CodeActivity
{

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.GetExtension<MyPersistanceParticipant>().MovieName = "Pursuit of Persistance";
        context.GetExtension<MyPersistanceParticipant>().Rating = "VH";
        context.GetExtension<MyPersistanceParticipant>().Price = Convert.ToDecimal(1);

    }
}
```

When I debug the CollectValues function , I can see that the code is running properly and I am able to see the values in immediate window. But the data wouldnt save in the Store.

Any pointers on what might be wrong ?

I doubt if I am using the namespace correctly

**static XNamespace xNS = XNamespace.Get("IamaUniqueNamespace");**

I have tried a couple of names including one fromthe Workflow XAML file but none seems  to work.
Is there a way I can debug what is going wrong ? I do not get any error at all.

Edit 1:
I was able to resolve my issue
I had to add new promoted properties to make sure they get saved in the [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancePromotedPropertiesTable]
And make sure  that the query string was correct.

```
 //Add promoted properties 
        XNamespace dataNamespace = XNamespace.Get("IamaUniqueNamespace");
        List<XName> variantProperties = new List<XName>();
        variantProperties.Add(dataNamespace.GetName("MovieName"));
        variantProperties.Add(dataNamespace.GetName("Rating"));
        variantProperties.Add(dataNamespace.GetName("Price"));
        _instanceStore.Promote("additionalProperty", variantProperties, null);


        InstanceHandle handle = _instanceStore.CreateInstanceHandle();
        InstanceView view = _instanceStore.Execute(handle,
                                                        new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand(),
                                                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        handle.Free();
        _instanceStore.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;

        // Add instance stoe to app
        wfApp.InstanceStore = _instanceStore;
       // Add persistance participant as extension
        MyPersistanceParticipant mp = new MyPersistanceParticipant();
        wfApp.Extensions.Add(mp);
```

Edit 2 : My intention behind this question was to get the PersistenceParticipant to store additional properites in the [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancePromotedPropertiesTable]
Now that I think of it , the way I framed the question may not have been very clear.

Comment: I answered my own question was able to get the Persistence to work. check edit 1 on the question  above.